# Chrome/Firefox margin & padding issues: how to line these things up?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I am trying to do a very simple tab setup on my site, but I'm having some problems because of the margin/padding pixel differences between firefox & chrome. Here is a jsfiddle link to what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/xqhf6/3/

Here's what it looks like in chrome:
[image: chrome]

Here's what it looks like in firefox:
[image: firefox]

Basically, here's the setup I have:

- .mydiv { ... } : each box is a mydiv that has a padding of 6px and a
  1px borders on left, right & top.
- .header { ... } : contains the two
  divs with borders at the top and has a bottom border
- .subheader { ...
  } : sits underneath the header (contains other stuff on the right
  that is irrelevant).

I have tried to set a color for the subheader, tried to increase its z-index to be greater than that of the header and yet nothing works. I just want the little dangling borders to go away.

Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks Stack Overflow!

**UPDATE** Here is a jsfiddle link to what I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/xqhf6/3/
**UPDATE 2** In trying some of the options, it looks like my best bet is try and figure out a way to use the subheader to somehow mask the dangling borders. Not able to do that (as I mentioned, nothing works when I play around with z-index/subheader opacity & color)

Ringo

Comment: please set up a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) that reproduces the problem...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3cKc9/ -- cool site by the way! If you look at that little example in firefox vs. chrome, you will see that the chrome version has the two spans slightly raised.

Comment: mh. there are some differences between chrome and firefox in the jsfiddle. however, the jsfiddle looks a bit different than the pictures in your question. could you rephrase, and explain more clearly what you need?

Comment: Well I just want to know how to make sure there are no differences between firefox & chrome. The only difference the screenshots and jsfiddle are different is because my screenshots use different colors. Otherwise, its exactly the same. I just cut the bottom portion (intersections of divs) for the screenshot.

I want to be able to at least just overlap the subheader on top of the above divs so that the dangling borders are not visible (in the screenshot). Check this out, it has the dangling borders I'm talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/3cKc9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get some weird effects if you try to apply a border to an `inline` element. Change your `<span>` elements to `display: inline-block;`.

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/2A2s8/

Comment: If for whatever reason you don't want to do this, you could also set `.header` or `body` to have `line-height: 1`, which seems to solve the problem as well.

Comment: that works really nicely for the jsfiddle, but I guess the other styling I have / margins I have still cause this 1px difference. Is there anyway I can use a subheader underneath to mask the dangling border? I tried both methods you have suggested and they still are causing the same issues... but thanks so much for your help so far, I really appreciate it!

Comment: It would be great if I had something to look at that wasn't working. If I can't reproduce your error, I won't really know how to fix it. If you can't do that, try using Chrome's Developer Tools or Firefox's Firebug to narrow down on what is causing the extra margins.

Comment: OK so here's my code pretty much exactly the way I have it on my site: http://jsfiddle.net/xqhf6/3/

Comment: you are perhaps the nicest person on the internet. Thank you SO much for your help!! Works perfectly :D I will use this same method for tabs from now onwards, thanks so much again.